# How to avoid multipath noise

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, wifi, bluetooth-low-energy

I have a device that broadcasts BLE advertisments, I am trying to measure the RSSI level of the broadcasts on another device (I am trying to do indoor triangulation for location estimation)
When I measure the RSSI over time (when both devices are static and there is no movement inside the room over time) I can see that the RSSI varies over time

But when I measure the RSSI over time using another device, I can see that the RSSI is quite static

The room is the same, the location of the devices is quite random so I guess that this difference is not due to certain location of any of the devices,

Why is one device more stable than the other? what can affect the signal stability over time? (the caster and the environment are the same in both cases)

thanks

Comment: Most bluetooth devices aren't stable in frequency and output strength, as this is allowed by specification and making it more stable is more costly.

Comment: yes, but I can clearly see on one antenna that the signal is stable (flat, actually) while on the other I get variation,
and as I said, this occurs in the same environment, same time, and same transmitter,
what can cause one antenna to receive siginificant variation when the other receive none?

Answer (score 2):

Moving your body close to the receiver will create this effect. Are you sure that this isn't happening?

The bottom line with RSSI is, if one receiver has a much weaker signal than the other, the effects of local body movements will appear much more pronounced. RSSI is (usually, in a lot of RF chips) a logarithmic output proportional to dbV (or dBm) received on the antenna so a lower output level may have variations on it that can be much more easily seen than when RSSI is higher.

You may also be witnessing on the device with the "flat" RSSI saturation of the input transistors. This means RSSI is maxed out and will inevitably look flat.

Here's a picture of RSSI output voltage against received power: -

[image]

If your directly received signal is -90 dBm and you have a reflected signal at -91 dBm your net RSSI might vary between -88 dBm and -92 dBm whereas the same level of reflected signal adding or subtracting to a directly received signal of -80 dBm might produce a figure that varies between -79.99 dBm to 80.01 dBm - i.e. hardly any noticeable variation.

Notice also  that a strongly received signal (> -50 dBm) will tend to be on the more flattened part of the scale.

Comment: Hi, 
I'm sure no one is moving near the transmitter or any of the receivers, and this is not flat due to saturation - since when there is some movement near my devices and can see the RSSI changes (in the flat device)

the situation is - that in the exact same conditions two antennas report on different output, not just different level (which is ofcourse understood) but on different variations between the samples.

I guess the the quality of the antennas is the key for the difference.. 
Do you have any other suggestions? Do you know properties can affect the antenna's reception's stability?10x

Comment: Maybe channel interference from a transmitter you are not aware of?

Comment: What do you mean?

could it cause intererence in only one of the two devices receiving the signal?

Comment: If positioned differently to receiver A, receiver B might not pick up anything from a rogue transmitter due to coincidental cancellation of multi-path signals.

Comment: Are the two receivers the same? If not, I'd bet that the "flat" one does an averaging, or a max or min-detect on the RSSI.

Comment: They are not the same, 
I thought so too, but I see the when I try to iterfere with the reception - for example, by standing near the receiver, it responds immediatly with RSSI change, I take sample every tens of miliseconds, when an advertisment is being broadcast...
and since the advertisment is being broadcast only once - I guess there is not much to avarage - I ask the device for the RSSI the advertisment was received with